# Selenium Web driver xpath, span locator

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-rc, xpath

Selenium Webdriver. Looking to Locate New Article from following code. Please note this is under an iframe.

```
<img class="rtbIcon" src="/icons/16/app/shadow/document_add.png" alt="">
                                 <span class="rtbText">New Article</span>
```

I have tried to locate with xpath and many other ways. But following is what I get everytime

Code : `driver.findElement(By.xpath("id('RadToolBar1'):div:div:div:ul:li[3]:a:span:span:span:span"));`

Result:
The given selector `id('RadToolBar1'):div:div:div:ul:li[3]:a:span:span:span:span` is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:

New article has no name, id so please if some one can help find me solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath seems to be wrong. The best way to get the xpath for any element on a page is by installing mozilla add on - [Fire Bug](http://getfirebug.com/). You can inspect any element using this add on and also copy the correct xpath of your element present on the page.

This should be your xpath -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='rtbText']"));
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Article"));
```

One of these should work. Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have to firebug installed but it is of no help This is what I get.                                        <div class="rtbOuter">
<div class="rtbMiddle">
<div class="rtbInner">
<ul class="rtbUL">
<li class="rtbItem rtbBtn ">
<li class="rtbItem rtbBtn">
<li class="rtbItem rtbBtn rtbItemFocused">
<a class=" rtbWrap" href="#">
<span class="rtbOut">
<span class="rtbMid">
<span class="rtbIn">
<img class="rtbIcon" src="/icons/16/app/shadow/document_add.png" alt="">
<span class="rtbText">New Article</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="rt

Comment: Please check New Article is what I need to click on. Can i locate it some different way.

Comment: I am giving you from div it starts as there is limitation on text to be Enetered.                                                              <div>

<div class="rtbOuter">
<div class="rtbMiddle">
<div class="rtbInner">
<ul class="rtbUL">
<li class="rtbItem rtbBtn ">
<li class="rtbItem rtbBtn">
<li class="rtbItem rtbBtn rtbItemFocused">
<a class=" rtbWrap" href="#">
<span class="rtbOut">
<span class="rtbMid">
<span class="rtbIn">
<img class="rtbIcon" src="/icons/16/app/shadow/document_add.png" alt="">
<span class="rtbText">New Article</span>
</span>
</span>
</span>

</ul>

Comment: Thank you for your help. I Tried all of them  Results are Unable to locate element: for all 3. I have to click on that New Article in order to get to next screen.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the entire source of your HTML page? Can you do that?

Comment: No Luck with two of them as well. Unable to locate element. I even have placed this command (driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);)before link I execute to locate New Article. So there is no reason for page to load. Still struggling to get click on New Article.

Comment: Can you tell me which version of browser and selenium standalone jar you are using?

Comment: I cannot edit question and tried to create new question but again too much text invloved so couldnt save it. can I attach you and send it to ur email id, mine is sagar_12384@yahoo.com

Comment: sure, send it to haridnr@gmail.com

Comment: selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0jar is what I am using